# Java library to convert HTML document to PCL

Tags: java, html, printer-control-language

Does anyone know of a Java library that can be used to convert an HTML document to PCL format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/output.html) for this purpose.